# Rselenium - Javascript/HTML

Tags: rselenium

Can anyone give me some advice by using FindElement to click some button in the website, which is under the Javascript function.

```
After<script type="text/javascript">, I couldn't select the id or name or 
class underneath the <script type="text/javascript">. (It's like a drop down 
list, which I want the remote desk can click it to enter next drop down list)
How can I >deal with this kind of subcategories?
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Would be great if you provide some code. Then we can help you to locate element

Comment: window['action_tbi_95a379ab_f798_45f5_a41d_f56efd42514b'] = function() {
  var go = new Object();
 go.gridName = 'das_death_audit_results';



This is part of the code in the HTML. So I want to get to the tab results under death audit. But it's underneath of the function. So I couldn't use the FindElement function to get it. @Andrei Suvorkov

Comment: can you show HTML code? Right click on the button -> inspect